# How to keep data in each tab in browser individually

Tags: jquery, tabs

I got a website which display a list of information, and this information can be edited and updated.

If i were to open the first data in one tab (Tab A) and the second data in a another tab (Tab B). Then go back to the first tab(Tab A) to update the information it will then update the information to the latest data i click which is the second data (Tab B).

Is there a way to prevent this without using the browser's private session for example google chrome's incognito window.

Comment: Why do you want to get the view out of sync with your data?

Comment: Because the information is updated to the wrong column. It is updated to the second data (Tab B) , instead of first data (Tab A) when i update my information using the Tab A